# Constraints programmatically and with Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, xcode-storyboard, masonry-ios-osx

It is possible to set constraints programmatically and while using Storyboards? I am using this https://github.com/raphaelschaad/RSPlayPauseButton as well as this for constraints https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry. However I they are not being displayed correctly:
[image: Bad] [image: Good]

The image on the left is not being displayed correctly, and it not clickable (it is a button).

Relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _playPauseButton = [[RSPlayPauseButton alloc] init];
    _playPauseButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [_playPauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playPauseButtonDidPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:_playPauseButton];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self.playPauseButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.center.equalTo(self.view).with.offset(10);
        }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adding width/height constraints for the `playPauseButton`, try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _playPauseButton = [[RSPlayPauseButton alloc] init];
    _playPauseButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [_playPauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playPauseButtonDidPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:_playPauseButton];

    [playPauseButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.center.equalTo(self.view).with.offset(10);
        make.width.equalTo(@(50));
        make.height.equalTo(@(50));
    }];
}
```

Comment: You should probably link to the library you're using for `mas_makeConstraints`.

Comment: The asker is using the `Masonry` too.